# Notify when an element is rendered in the DOM: Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a div in my template which contains a bunch of information, but because the information is dynamically populated by making an API call I have an *ngIf condition on the div:

```
<div class="user-information" *ngIf="userInfoLoaded">
  <div [id]="userInfoObj.id">
     ........
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to grab the nested div with id=userInfoObj.id to do something with it, but the problem I'm facing is that I don't know when the API comes back with a response, so something like:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  console.log(document.getElementById(this.userInfoObj.id));
}
```

would not work because it won't be rendered in the DOM until we have the actual response. So is their a way to let the component know when this particular div is rendered in the DOM? Somebody suggested me to use a Promise, but I'm not sure how that would work in this case.

Comment: There is probably a better solution than the one you're trying to use. But to know that, you need to tell us precisely what you mean by "do something with it". What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @JBNizet I will be using scrollintoview function to scroll the page to that div using Angular fragments

Comment: OK. The best way is probably to use ViewChildren, then. See https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren. You give a name to your div (rather than an ID): `<div #userInfo>`. Then you use `@ViewChildren('userInfo')` in your component, you subscribe to the QueryList's changes, and when the div appears in the view, you do what you want to do.

Comment: that works @JBNizet. But my only concern is if you do that then the subscribe will be getting executed while you're on that page. I verified that by writing a console log inside the subscribe body and whenever I'm interacting with the UI of that page (unrelated to that div), the subscribe is being called. So should I unsubscribe inside the subscribe body once I receive the data, so that it only gets executed once?

Comment: UPDATE: I just tried something like:
queryList.changes.toPromise().then(data => console.log('called:', data));

in the above I'm converting the observable received by changes to a promise so that I receive the changes only once. But, the console inside promise never gets called.. not sure why

Comment: Because toPromise() waits for the completion of the observable, and emits the last event. You can use first() or take(1).

Answer (score 1):

You can try AfterContentChecked which gets triggered everytime the dom changes